# To linq To SQL or not... that is the question?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Our team is now beginning to look at jumping from 2.0 to 3.5 and have been reviewing all the new stuff....

So, with the whole Linq to SQL not being heavily improved in the future should we ignore it completely?

It seems that it may fit of our needs very well BUT I imagine so could entity framework even if it may add more complexity.

So avoid Linq To SQL like to plague and go with entity framework instead or jump on in, Linq To SQL will be just fine in 4.0 and future releases even without improvements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pick LINQ only because it is simpler, and when you finish your application, and are looking at optimizing, and refactoring, then you can try Entities, and see if you have any performance improvements, or if it makes the code better.

I tend to start with the simpler, faster-to-develop, method, to get the functionality finished, then I refactor, then optimize.

Comment: I have been reading like mad for the past month and have gone back and forth.  The following links have helped me go over the edge to go with L2S (especially since I am learning and think my complexity needs will be low)

http://naspinski.net/post/Linq-to-SQL-vs-Linq-to-Entities--Revisited.aspx

http://naspinski.net/post/Why-I-decided-to-stick-with-Linq-to-SQL-over-Linq-to-Entities.aspx

Comment: I figure starting with L2S will be a great start and worse case scenario as you mentioned, move to entities if I feel the need or the feature set becomes undeniable at some point.

I also as a side note was wondering about what's so awesome about LINQ in general.  I have been coding sprocs/sql for years and thus felt what is the big deal....  Must say the LinqPad website sample of why LINQ beats SQL was a real eye opener and perhaps my last gasp of doing SPs and SQL as my first means for DB access shall we say...

http://www.linqpad.net/WhyLINQBeatsSQL.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Everything I've read seems to suggest that Linq2SQL will still be around for a while.  I would, if I were you, just pick the one that best suits the problem you're trying to solve.  I might be a little biased toward using the Entity Framework because it's more abstract and might be a good capability for you and your team to have, and because Visual Studio 2008 has a designer for it.

I just don't think it's that big a deal for a few years.  Just pick the one you like the best for now.

**Update**: lest there be any confusion - using the EF doesn't mean giving up Linq.  Linq can already be used with the EF.

Answer (score 1):

Very similiar to my question @ [Switching to LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806159/switching-to-linq)

Might offer further insight/opinions.

Personally, I am going to start focusing on EF since everything I see coming from MS is that LINQ is just the beginning and a big part of the foundation of EF.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have picked EF in any case. I never liked the idea that LINQ to SQL mapped directly to the database structure. I greatly preferred the idea of EF, where I can decide what entities I want to present to users, and then map them to the database tables as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL and Entity framework are not comets passing by. They are real coding revolutions !

We can now query databases in 1 hour where it took us 1 day before !

Do not hesitate to jump. If .Net 4.0 does not suport LINQ to SQL or Entity framework, just stick to 3.5 !

:o)

All the best, Sylvain.

Answer (score 0):

If LINQ to SQL fits your needs, then go with it. Its really a very powerful RAD tool.

EF will give you more flexibility, but also perhaps unnecessary complexity.

Its a shame LINQ to SQL isn't moving forward anymore, but I'd stick to it until EF really matures and allows equal RAD development, unless of course, you need EF features now.

Comment: Curiosity: What does LINQ to SQL offer in terms of RAD that EF does not?

Comment: @john: hey John. As with most RAD tools, a lot of abstraction takes place. The downside of this is of course you have less options. The plus side is everything "just works", albeit it "just works" in one way.

With LINQ to SQL, the process is very intuitive, and after dragging a few tables into the DBML designer, you can start querying your Entities efficiently with IQueryables pretty much instantly. The few options available to you are in the datacontext constructors and DBML properties dialog window. So things are kept real simple.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it depends. Everyone else so far has put things very well.

Use LINQ-to-SQL if you don't mind the fact that your eventual object model is going to very closely mirror your database. There's not a lot you can do with or to a LINQ-to-SQL model if you find that you want to model things differently.

Use EF if you want to potentially use the same framework to point to multiple types of data, or if you'd like to abstract your database model more than is possible in LINQ-to-SQL.

I don't have any data on, say, performance differences between the two models, unfortunately.

I wouldn't say the fact that MS isn't doing a lot of active development on LINQ-to-SQL should necessarily scare you away. Its a very good, very, very basic object mapping solution.

Comment: I agree with all of these points. This is typically how I think about the different ORMs when choosing.